# twitter bootstrap 3 tab view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have tab view using twitter bootstrap 3:

http://jsfiddle.net/K9LpL/2/

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
</ul>

    <div id='content' class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <ul>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
        <ul>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="settings"></div>
    </div>
```

This code does not work to me. Most of examples on net are not with 3rd version. It would be great if anybody tell me what my problem is or even if giving me a standard working example(with bootstrap 3).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can activate tab using `data-toggle` without js or with js as shown below. For more info see this **[documentation.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)**

See this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K9LpL/4/)** Add id `myTab` to `ul` and run this below js

JS

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

Answer (score 18):

You forgot the `data-toggle` attribute on your links.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="pill">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="pill">Profile</a></li>
   <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="pill">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jofrysutanto/K9LpL/3/

This is actually in Bootstrap 3.0 documentation as well: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

**Update**

As described in comment, `data-toggle="pill"` and `data-toggle="tab"` can be used interchangeably depends on the style you're after.

> You can activate a tab or pill navigation without writing any JavaScript by simply specifying data-toggle="tab" or data-toggle="pill" on an element. Adding the nav and nav-tabs classes to the tab ul will apply the Bootstrap tab styling, while adding the nav and nav-pills classes will apply pill styling.

Comment: +1 This answer is more accurate than the accepted one *(doesn't need to use jQuery to do the job)*, just a side note. The OP is using `tabs` and the example is using `pills`. You can just switch from one to another without problem.